# Adding Cards to the bottom of an immutable Deck

Tags: c#, algorithm, data-structures, immutability

*Background:* I created a custom `Card` struct with `Suit` and `Value` properties represented by enums to model a playing card. I created a `Deck` class which contains cards and has several options for manipulating them. It stores cards as a `Queue<Card>` because that made the most logical sense and made most implementations easy.

To practice coding, I decided I wanted to build an `ImmutableDeck` that couldn't be modified. It's methods return new `ImmutableDeck`s and use `out` parameters to return drawn `Card`s. I modeled it on Eric Lippert's `ImmutableStack`, creating an `Empty` Deck, making constructors private, and having two members: the "Top Card", and a "pointer" to the next `ImmutableDeck`.

```
public class ImmutableDeck
{
    static readonly EmptyDeck Empty = new EmptyDeck ();
    readonly Card top;
    readonly ImmutableDeck next;

    ImmutableDeck ()
    {
    }

    ImmutableDeck (Card top, ImmutableDeck next)
    {
        this.top = top;
        this.next = next;
    }

    public int Count => 1 + next.Count;
    public bool IsEmpty => this == Empty;
    public Card Top => top;

    public Card Bottom ()
    {
        var temp = next;
        while (!temp.next.IsEmpty)
        {
            temp = temp.next;
        }
        return temp.Top;
    }

    public ImmutableDeck DrawCard (out Card c)
    {
        c = top;
        return next;
    }

    public ImmutableDeck PutCardOnTop (Card c)
    {
        return new ImmutableDeck (c, this);
    }

    public ImmutableDeck PutCardOnBottom (Card c)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException ("PutCardOnBottom");
    }



    public class EmptyDeck : ImmutableDeck
    {
        public new int Count
        {
            get;
        } = 0;

        public new bool IsEmpty
        {
            get;
        } = true;

        public new Card Top
        {
            get
            {
                throw new Deck.DeckEmptyException ();
            }
        }

        public new Card Bottom ()
        {
            throw new Deck.DeckEmptyException ();
        }

        public new ImmutableDeck DrawCard (out Card c)
        {
            throw new Deck.DeckEmptyException ();
        }

        public new ImmutableDeck PutCardOnTop (Card c)
        {
            return new ImmutableDeck (c, this);
        }

        public new ImmutableDeck PutCardOnBottom (Card c)
        {
            return new ImmutableDeck (c, this);
        }
    }
}
```

*Problem:* Clearly, these decks can be constructed by building cards on top of cards on top of empty decks. It's fairly powerful. But I'm struggling to implement a way to allow a `Card` to be added to the bottom. So far, all I've come up with is that I need to follow the `next` pointers through the chain until I reach the end (Empty), but I'm not sure what the next steps are.

A good solution will provide working code that correctly returns a new `ImmutableDeck` instance where the passed in `Card` is now the last card in the deck as well as an explanation of how the solution works.

Comment: My personnal guess would be to use a recusive function to travel all the way down to the last decj and put add it a next deck. Then each call would return itself to the caller, essentially making the first call retuen the whole deck. If that makes sense to you I can make a real answer when I have time (I'm on mobile right now)

Comment: @FrancisLord i was thinking of something similar but was having a hard time wrapping my head around it--id love to see your answer when you get time

Comment: Since you didn't comment on Scott Hannen's (now deleted) answer, is there any reason you can't just use an `ImmutableList<>`?

Comment: @DavidG this is mostly a practice exercise, but i like my types to be comprehensive. A list doesnt have the same semantics as a deck, and id like to try and implement this from scratch if i can.

Comment: What semantics exactly do you think are missing?

Comment: @DavidG i could probably redecorate an immutable list to have the right method names and such, and if thats the best solution that exists, i can live with that. But im really hoping to find a solution to this problem.

Comment: Well you can reinvent the wheel (which is reasonable for your own benefit and practice) but I personally would consider it a waste of energy. I don't see any problem in either having some extension methods for `Immutable<Card>` or even inheriting it and adding a few methods of your own.

Comment: One thing you're going to run into is that, while this is possible, a Stack really isn't the right data structure if you want the ability to add to either end. (I think @FrancisLord 's appraoch will work, and might be fun to program, but it will be a bit messy and slow). I'd suggest experimenting with immutable trees, if you're doing this for your own education?

Comment: @EdwardPeters as i eventually plan to simulate full games of War, speed is not an overly critical factor. How do you think trees will help?

Comment: If you need to add to both ends try to chunk your list - than you'll only need to update small portion and all its parents (that's where I believe @EdwardPeters comes from with trees).

Comment: @BenKnoble Stacks tend to be expressed as singly-linked-lists, and as such it's difficult to insert into the edges without traversing the entire structure (trees can be nicer, as if they're "well balanced" the depth only grows with the log of the size, allowing for efficient access/update). I also suggest trees because they're an incredibly commonly used data structure (more than people realize, because they're often the "back end" for other structures), and from my experience are especially important for functional/immutable programming.

Comment: Some variation of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-tree would work for adding to both ends.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Leandro said, there are multiple ways to do this. Here is mine (using the same class you already have). The only problem I can see is that it requires that you assign a value to the `next` field, which is read-only in your implementation. I understand why it is so (you can't modify what's under another card before taking that card out), but in this case I'm sure it'd be possible to do it without changing the this field.

```
Public ImmutableDeck PutCardOnBottom (Card c)
{
    if (!this.next.IsEmpty)
        this.next.PutCardOnBottom(c);
    else
        this.next = new ImmutableDeck(c, ImmutableDeck.Empty);

    return this;
}
```

**Note** : I'm not 100% sure about return the instance of the 1st call, but I think that's what makes sense since the top of the deck didn't change.

**Other Note** : Only issue I can see with this (apart from what I noted before) is that if you have a *really* big deck, you'll encounter a `StackOverflowException`. I could have done it in a similar fashion to your implementation of the `Bottom` method, but I figured a 52 card deck would not be an issue, and I love recursive functions :)

Comment: This looks good--ill have to try and think it out to make sure the logic makes sense to me, but it seems in order

Comment: Based on your answer, I have something like this. Could you sanity check it for me?     `if (IsEmpty)
   {
    return PutCardOnTop (c);
   }
   return next.PutCardOnBottom (c);`

Comment: @BenKnoble I don't think that works, cause if you call put `PutCardOnTop(c)`, you basically end up with a deck which has the given card on top, and the last card on the bottom all you lose all reference to the cards on top of it [which are going to get garbage collected :-)]. Plus by returning the result of the recursive call, you are effectively returning the last call since each card is going to return to its parent the cards bellow itself which will get passed up to the first call on top.

Comment: Hmm i think youre right... It will just return up the recursive chain and lose all the other cards. Rats. Ill take another look at it in the morning.

Comment: I might have it: `if (next.IsEmpty) { return new ImmutableDeck (top, Empty.PutCardOnTop(c)); } return new ImmutableDeck(top, next.PutCardOnBottom(c));` which i think might be replaceable with one line due to the way EmptyDeck is set up, but id rather stick with the two line conditional

Comment: This might work, but I'm not sure about the `PutCardOnTop` thing. Maybe give it a try and step along in debug to see :)

Comment: Will do. For now, ill mark yours as answer. It works, after all

Answer (score 3):

First off, if you are interested in immutable queue-like data structures that have cheap access to both ends, read my article on immutable deques.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/01/22/immutability-in-c-part-10-a-double-ended-queue/

Deques are often much more complicated that stacks and queues, but very interesting data structures.

A simpler solution to your problem is: break it down into three smaller problems:

- Insert onto the top -- you've solved this already.
- Remove from the top -- you've solved this already.
- Reverse a deck.

How to implement reverse?  Well, if a deck is empty then it is already reversed. If it is not empty, then remove the top card, insert it onto an empty deck, and keep doing that until it is empty.

So now you can do reverse. Insert onto the bottom is reverse, insert onto the top, reverse again.

And of course remove from the bottom is similarly easy: reverse, remove from the top, reverse again.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric; this seems logically to make the most sense, though i believe i have some kind of recursive solution. Incidentally, i have read the article though had forgotten it. I may change my recursive solution to the reversal method.

Answer (score 0):

Use a list that will automatically put the cards at the bottom of your deck. I had something similar and I used List and that worked perfect for me. Hope, this helps.